# Finding largest number in Java

Tags: java, java-7

I am trying to find the large number in java by using the integer parameter. I converted the integer value to string but the problem is, it failed on the run and did not show the expected result.

Here is the case:

Given an integer n, it returns the largest number that contains exactly n digits only when n is non-zero.

- For n = 1, the output should be largestNumber(n) = "9".
- For n = 2, the output should be largestNumber(n) = "99".
- For n = 3, the output should be largestNumber(n) = "999".
- For n =0, the output should be largestNumber(n) = "-1".

**Constraints
0 ≤ |n| ≤ 10**

Here is the java code :

```
class Result {
  /*
   * Complete the 'largestNumber' function below.
   *
   * The function is expected to return a STRING.
   * The function accepts INTEGER n as parameter.
   */
public static String largestNumber(int n) { // Write your code here
String res = Integer.toString(n);
return res;
}
                   
}public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));
int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim()); String result = Result.largestNumber(n);
        bufferedWriter.write(result);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the result of the screenshot.

[image: Result]

Comment: Why should `n = 0` result in `largestNumber(n) = "-1"`? It should be `0` since all the other values are `= 10^n - 1`. So for 0, `10^0 - 1 == 0`. To say it should be -1 is an anomaly in the specification and the requestor should be challenged.

Comment: @k314159 That formula just happens to work for positive `n`, but within the context of the problem, 0 has one digit, not zero digits. `-1` is used to indicate that this is a special case with no clear solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is repeat the digit "9" `n` times, with the exception of returning `-1` for `0`.

```
public static String largestNumber(int n) {
     if(n == 0) return "-1";
     // for Java 11+: return "9".repeat(n);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) sb.append('9');
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: In Java 11 or higher, you can repeat a string simply with `"9".repeat( n )`

Comment: I'd like to offer an alternative: String.format("%d",(int)Math.pow(10, n)-1)

Comment: @GonenI using `String.format` for trivial conversions like `String.format("%d",…)` is not better than `"" + …` or `String.valueOf(…)`. When you look at [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and follow the [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)) link and consider the underlying framework’s features (locale sensitive formatting, layout justification and alignment), it’s not surprising that it will consume far more resources than string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static String largestNumber(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return "-1";
    return BigInteger.TEN.pow(n).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).toString();
}
```